# How does a portable Thread Specific Storage Mechanism's Naming Scheme Generate Thread Relative Unique Identifiers?

Tags: multithreading, boost-thread, systems-programming, low-level-api, thread-specific-storage

A **portable** thread specific storage **reference/identity** mechanism, of which boost/thread/tss.hpp is an instance, needs a way to generate a unique keys for itself. This key is unique in the scope of a thread, and is subsequently used to retrieve the object it references. This mechanism is used in code written in a thread neutral manner.

Since boost is a portable example of this concept, how specifically does such a mechanism work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost thread is portable to the pthread threading library (for unix) and the windows win32 low-level-API's. The library allows a reference to be created which is unique in each thread of execution. The global C API `errno` is [presented as an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) of this concept in Boost's documentation.

---

**Ignore If you Want -- it's just a trace through the source code finding the function of interest**

The crux of the matter begins in `[boost]/boost/thread/tss.hpp` with the `get` function of `thread_specific_ptr` and the `reset` function -- i.e., the aquisition and the destruction, respectively, of the object referenced. Note: the data object is not placed in the reference of `thread_specific_ptr`'s ctor, or destroyed by the dtor. The get and reset function call `set_tss_data` and `get_tss_data`. Focusing just on the setting aspect of the functionality, the important function call, `get_current_thread_data`, indirects via the cpp file `[boost]/libs/thread/src/[libname]/thread.cpp` via a chain of function calls. In `get_current_thread_data` there is a function call `create_current_thread_tls_key` and this is the function that will create a unique identifier for the `thread_specific_ptr` object.

---

`create_current_thread_tls_key` calls `TlsAlloc()` on win32 ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686801(VS.85).aspx)) and `pthread_key_create` for pthread ([link](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.html)). These calls assure that upon initialization of the ptr, the ptr receives a unique identifier usable in an API-specific manner to retrieve the object's data. The specific threading API uses the thread-id (context specific and resolved by the library itself) and the object identifier to return the object specific to the context of a certain thread.